# Running external program using pipes and passing arguments in python

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen

I tried that, but when I try to print these arguments it returns no values.
I submit my code below:

script1 that runs external python program (script2)

```
#(...)
proc = subprocess.Popen(['export PYTHONPATH=~/:$PYTHONPATH;' +
    'export environment=/path/to/environment/;' +
    'python /path/to/my/program/myProgram.py',
    '%(date)s' %{'date':date}, '%(time)s' %{'time':time}],
    stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
#(...)
```

script2 that is being run by the script1

```
#(...)
print sys.argv[0] #prints the name of the command
print sys.argv[1] #it suppose to print the value of the first argument, but it doesn't
print sys.argv[2] #it suppose to print the value of the second argument, but it doesn't
#(...)
```

Comment: have you tried using `shlex.split` ?

Comment: no, not really, would that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version of script 1:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('python /path/to/my/program/myProgram.py %s %s' % (date, time),
                        stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True,  
                        env = {'PYTHONPATH': '~/:$PYTHONPATH',
                               'environment': '/path/to/environment/'})
```

It should make it easier to find your problem if it doesn't work; but I think it will.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, in fact it wouldn't even print the output of script2

Comment: Did you try it after my edit? And did you try it WITHOUT the `=PIPE` arguments?

Comment: I just tried without =PIPE arguments, but it throws error, as it cannot import library, so it probably didn't set the envelope correctly

Answer (score 1):

[Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) say that when specifying shell=True any additional args are treated as args to the shell, not to the command. To make it work, just set shell to False. I don't see why you need it to be True.

edit: I see you want to use shell to set environment variables. Use the env argument to set the environment variables instead.

Comment: The other two answers address important issues, but this is the main problem.

Comment: I need shell to be true, as I need to export libraries first

Comment: Like I said. Use env argument to set the environment instead. If you need to copy  any environment variables from your current environment then copy `environ` in the `os` module.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `Popen`'s `env` parameter to pass environment variables:
2. Don't use `shell=True` unless you have to. It can be a [security
   risk (see Warning)](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module).

test.py:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import datetime as dt
now=dt.datetime.now()
date=now.date()
time=now.strftime('%X')

proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(
    'python /tmp/test2.py %(date)s %(time)s'%{'date':date,
                                         'time':time}),
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        env={'PYTHONPATH':'~/:$PYTHONPATH',
                             'environment':'/path/to/environment/'})

out,err=proc.communicate()
print(out)
print(err)
```

test2.py:

```
import sys
import os

print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])
print(os.environ['environment'])
for i in range(3):
    print(sys.argv[i])
```

yields

```
~/:$PYTHONPATH
/path/to/environment/
/tmp/test2.py
2011-08-09
17:50:04
```

Comment: If `print sys.argv[0]` is working, then the pipes aren't his problem. Good call on the `env` parameter.